# Python start for loop on next line if a statement is not true

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
with open('./links.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        browser.get(line)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jw-media")))
        title = None
        network = None
        subnetwork = None
        html = browser.page_source
        if isinstance(title, str):
            title = title.text
        else:
            with open('./notfound.txt', 'a') as h:
                h.write(line)
                h.write('\n')
                h.close()
                next(line)
```

For each line in f it is going to set the variables title, network and sub network to None and every time a page loads with the url (which is each line) from links.txt it will set the variables to the correct strings. The if statement will check whether the variables have changed and if they haven't I want it to go to the next string and start from the top settings the variables to None, loading the page, etc. is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I am not fully certain this is what you mean, but you might be looking for the `continue` statement or the `break` statement

Comment: For each line in f it  is going to set the variables title, network and sub network to None and every time a page loads with the url (which is each line) from links.txt it will set the variables to the correct strings. The if statement will check whether the variables have changed and if they haven't I want it to go to the next string and start from the top settings the variables to None, loading the page, etc.
edit: hopefully that explains it better, I think the break statement is what I am looking for

Comment: Your code has several issues, but please re-phrase the question explaining what you actually want to do. Are you trying to find if the "title" of the web page has a given value or if the page was found (i.e. it does not trigger a 404 error)? I cannot propose a solution without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: @testtest Your comment sounds to me like you'd actually want the `continue`, not the `break`. `continue` jumps to the next loop iteration. `break` fully stops the loop. See e.g. section 4.4 [in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for continue in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops this will go on to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `next(line)` statement makes no sense, as `line` is not an iterator (the loop construct is already taking care of incrementing that for you). Also, using `h.close()` inside the `with` block is wrong, as `close` will be automatically called when you leave the `with` block.
Finally, it is not a good practice to open and close the file at every iteration of the loop.

The code below addresses these points:

```py
with open('./links.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('./notfound.txt', 'a') as h:
        for line in f:
            browser.get(line.strip())   # Remove extraneous spaces, including the final '\n'
            WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jw-media")))
            title = browser.title  # This is how you get the title of the page
            network = None
            subnetwork = None
            html = browser.page_source
            if isinstance(title, str):  # Not sure what is your goal with this line
                title = title.text
            else:
                h.write(line)  # You don't need to add the '\n' because line already has it
```